# Rails api scaffold issue after setting activeadmin gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, scaffold

I'm just starting to work with rails-api, and I wanted to implement some admin user interface for the backend side. As I'm used to activeadmin gem, I tried to use it here. I followed some steps to enable the middleware needed to run it, since it was in API mode.

One of the steps was to change in the `application_controller.rb` the following:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
end
```

to

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
end
```

and then create a `api_controller.rb` and make it inherit from `ActionController::API`

```
class ApiController < ActionController::API
end
```

following these steps I have activeadmin running well. My problem is that now when I trie to run **rails generate scaffold** command to generate new models it stops at

```
invoke  inherited_resources_controller
```

and throws the next error:

```
Could not find "api_controller.rb" in any of your source paths.
```

I suppose that I can just could the controller manually and it would be fine(?), but I would still like to know why this happens and how to fix it as it would save me time.

Comment: [This closed IR PR](https://github.com/activeadmin/inherited_resources/pull/438) might be related, your solution looks good.

Answer (score 4):

after a lot of reading, I solved my problem adding this to my `application.rb`:

```
config.app_generators.scaffold_controller = :scaffold_controller
```